# Upload .mp3 file to public URL within Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am using Rails 4.0.0 and Ruby 2.0.0, and I have an app deployed to Heroku.

I want to give my users the ability to upload a mp3 file. After it is completed uploading, I need them to get access to the public URL of that mp3 file. Right now, I could upload the recordings myself in my `public` directory, and then I could access them at a public URL.

I need to replicate that ability for my users. Any thoughts on the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku generally doesn't want you to let people upload files onto the Heroku filesystem via your website.  You need to use a third party file storage system.  Most people use Amazon S3, and there are loads of detailed tutorials on how to use this with heroku (including on the heroku site).  Google for "heroku amazon s3" and you'll see loads of helpful stuff, eg

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3